# Slicing image to make a widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The image above has 6 gears(those circles with pointy edges). What I want to do is make them into separate pictures and then on each picture's hover the relevant line with the relevant text should pop up. How do I go about this problem?

The alignment of these gears should be the same after slicing the image.

I am having trouble in how should I approach this problem. One could be to slice them up then absolute position all of them, but it has to work on screens atleast the size of this image.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Try an image map. Here's a tool to help with that http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: Come on man. :/ What should I do to make it not too broad?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can draw this in Adobe Illustrator and save as a SVG. Then put it in html write animations and style to its elements. like normal we code for normal html tags.